# CSV file: For values within double quotes, replace commas with semi colon and remove double quotes

Tags: regex, perl, csv, awk, sed

I have a csv file of format:

```
value1, value2, "some text in the, quotes, with commas and "nested quotes", some more text", value3, value4
```

I want to replace the  commas within the outermost quotes of third field with ';' and remove the inner quotes. I have tried using "sed" but nothing has helped to replace the nested quotes.

Comment: Please note that the format described does not conform to any of the commonly accepted CSV formats, in which "Embedded double quote characters may then be represented by a pair of consecutive double quotes, or by prefixing an escape character such as a backslash ..." [wikipedia]).

Comment: This format is generated from the python script provided by Yelp [here](https://github.com/Yelp/dataset-examples/blob/master/json_to_csv_converter.py) to convert their json dataset to csv format.

Comment: That is a terrible attempt at CSV. Who knows what else that python script might be messing up? Get a better Json to CSV converter, one that at a minimum generates CSV in one of the common formats!

Comment: The better question to ask would perhaps be on how to convert JSON to CVS. This is known as an XY-problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could do it like this.
The criteria is even number of quotes within quoted field that is surrounded
by comma's as a field separator.

Note that if the csv does not abide by the above criteria, nothing will save it,
it can never be parsed.

`(?:^|,)\s*\K"([^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)+)"(?=\s*(?:,|$))`

Formatted:

```
 (?: ^ | , )
 \s* 
 \K 
 " 
 (                             # (1 start)
      [^"]* 
      (?:                           # Inner, even number of quotes

           "
           [^"]* 
           "
           [^"]* 
      )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 "    
 (?=
      \s* 
      (?: , | $ )
 )
```

Perl sample:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = 'value1, value2, "some text in the, quotes, with commas and "nested quotes", some more text", value3, value4';

sub innerRepl
{
    my ($in) = @_;
    return '"' . ($in =~ tr/,"/;/dr ) . '"';
}

$data =~ s/(?:^|,)\s*\K"([^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)+)"(?=\s*(?:,|$))/ innerRepl( $1 ) /eg;

print $data;
```

Output:

```
value1, value2, "some text in the; quotes; with commas and nested quotes; some more text", value3, value4
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a recursive regex to match nested quotes, and the tidiest way to alter the quotes and commas is an *expression* substitution in concert with a non-destructive transliteration which became available in v5.14 of Perl

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use v5.14;

my $str = 'value1, value2, "some text in the, quotes, with commas and "nested quotes", some more text", value3, value4';

$str =~ s{ " ( (?: [^"]++ | (?R) )* ) " }{ $1 =~ tr/,"/;/dr }egx;

print $str, "\n";
```

#### output

```
value1, value2, some text in the; quotes; with commas and nested quotes; some more text, value3, value4
```

Comment: Thank you, Borodin! This script works perfectly. But it removes even the outer quotes for me, which I can see in your output.

Comment: @Mansi: Yes, I'm sorry, that was output from an earlier version of the code which I forgot to update